# Android code stop responding when the edit text left empty

Tags: android

hi i am new learner of android and java.below this is my code. I having trouble to know where is the problem.
when i debug few times, it automatically  enter debug mode after that. to fix that i have to restart the phone again. I check with other apps, it work just fine. just for the apps that i currently working on.

problem :
1. if i didn't enter data into the "dateTo" the program will stopped.
2. enter debug mode itself.
3. when i get the data from the array atList, then i key in another 'dateTo" to retrieve another data, but it doesn't replace the current data value. tq

```
package com.example.m2mai;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RetrieveActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve);
    }
    public ArrayList<String> atList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dataList=new ArrayList<String>();


    public void getStream(View v)
    {   
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            return getData();

        }
        public long getDateTo() 
      {
        EditText toText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateTo);
        String To = toText.getText().toString();

        DateFormat dateFormatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dateTo = null;
        try {
            dateTo = dateFormatTo.parse(To);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long timeTo = dateTo.getTime();
        new Timestamp(timeTo);  
        return timeTo/1000;
      }

        protected String getData()
        {
            String toTS = ""+getDateTo();
            String decodedString="";
            String returnMsg="";
            String request = "http://api.carriots.com/devices/{API_KEY}/streams/?order=-1&max=2&at_to="+toTS;
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
            try {
                url = new URL(request); 
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //establish the parameters for the http post request
                connection.addRequestProperty("carriots.apikey", "somekey");
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
                //create a buffered reader to interpret the incoming message from the carriots system
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    returnMsg+=decodedString;
                }
                in.close();
                connection.disconnect();
                JSONObject nodeRoot = new JSONObject(returnMsg); 
                JSONArray res = nodeRoot.getJSONArray("result");

                 for (int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) 
                    {
                    JSONObject childJSON = res.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (childJSON.get("data")!=null)
                        {
                       String value = childJSON.getString("data");
                       dataList.add(value);
                       JSONObject node=new JSONObject(value);
                       atList.add(node.get("temperature").toString()); 
                        }
                    } 
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                returnMsg=""+e;
            }
            //Log.d("returnMsg",returnMsg.toString());
            return returnMsg;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
            //show the message returned from Carriots to the user

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            EditText myData1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            myData1.setText(atList.get(0));
            EditText myData=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            myData.setText(atList.get(1));      
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `long timeTo = dateTo.getTime();` will throw a `NullPointerException` when the `dateFormatTo.parse` method throws a `ParseException`. This is going to happen when you come into the method with the `To` string not matching the specified format.

You're not exiting out of the flow so the `long...getTime();` line runs, but `dateTo` is `null` resulting in a crash.

---

In the `onPostExecute`; you aren't verifying that `atList` has multiple elements. A JSON parse failure will leave `atList` empty and cause an index bounds exception for those 2 `get` calls.

---

These may not be the solutions to what you're seeing; but they will crash the app when these are hit in very likely situations; including the one you describe of an empty string for `To`.

As the comments mention; the logs will help see what's actually happening; but this is too big for a comment and those points are going to cause problems.

Comment: tq so much for your comment.

Comment: I sucessfully replace the data view each time key in a new value.
solution : move the arraylist declaration to the asyntask line